# How to fix memory leak from LINQ include function in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to retrieve a list of products from the database using the Products API where it returns a JSON result. For instance I have 5 products with each of the products have 5 prices based on the customer type. When I try to load the JSON list using Postman, I get a message from postman saying "response too large" since the response is over 50 MB. Where do I need to fix the memory leak and reduce the size of response?

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ProductList()
{
    var productlist = _productRepository
            .AllIncluding
            (
                p => p.Product_Prices,
                p => p.Product_Promotions,
                p => p.Product_Stocks,
                p => p.Product_Types,
                p => p.Units
            )
            .OrderBy(p => p.Product_Name)
            .ToList();

    var subcountylist = _subCountyRepository.GetAll();
    var countylist = _countyRepository.GetAll();
    var customertypelist = _customer_TypeRepository.AllIncluding(ct => ct.Customer_TypeEnums).ToList();

    List<Product_Price> product_Prices = new List<Product_Price>();

    foreach (var price_item in productlist)
    {
            foreach (var item in price_item.Product_Prices)
            {
                product_Prices.Add(item);
            }
    }

    List<Product_Stock> product_Stocks = new List<Product_Stock>();

    foreach (var stock_item in productlist)
    {
            foreach (var s_item in stock_item.Product_Stocks)
            {
                product_Stocks.Add(s_item);
            }
    }

    var results = from p in productlist
                  join pp in product_Prices on p.Id equals pp.Products.Id
                  //join s in subcountylist on pp.SubCounties.Id equals s.Id
                  join ct in customertypelist on pp.Customer_TypeEnums.Id equals ct.Customer_TypeEnums.Id
                  join ps in product_Stocks on p.Id equals ps.Products.Id
                  join c in countylist on ps.Counties.Id equals c.Id
                  select p;

    return Ok(results.Distinct());
}
```

The code for the `Product` model class:

```
public class Product : IEntityBase
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string ProductItem_ID { get; set; }
     public string Product_Name { get; set; }
     public string Product_Description { get; set; }
     public decimal Production_Price { get; set; } = 0;
     public DateTime Created_At { get; set; } = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").Trim());
     public DateTime? Updated_At { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for one product can have many prices
     public List<Product_Price> Product_Prices { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for one product can have many promotions
     public List<Product_Promotion> Product_Promotions { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for one product can have many stock
     public List<Product_Stock> Product_Stocks { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for product type
     public Product_Type Product_Types { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for one product can have many purchase order item
     public List<Purchase_Order_Item> Purchase_Order_Items { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for one product can have many sale item
     public List<Sale_Item> Sale_Items { get; set; }

     // Foreign key for unit
     public Unit Units { get; set; }
}
```

The code for `Allincluding` repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
        IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

       return query.AsEnumerable();
}
```

The code for `GetAll` repository method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Set<T>().AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: This is not a "Memory leek" if the json you want to get is 50mb large? How big the response should be? There are a lot of mistakes in your queries where you are pulling stuff into memory so there might be a more optimal solution but none of this is a memory leek?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The response I was trying to get a result of the all the records using left join with the LINQ query.In the process using Newtonsoft reference handling with ignore. It will format the json with all the objects in include. So I was trying to figure out if loading the product, price and stocks separately to store them in their respective list classes variables and applying a where clause query in either of the list variables to obtain a result as a solution to reduce the response size.

Comment: This is the down side of having so many layers of abstraction, you protect yourself from implementation changes but you the cost in terms of performance and/or resource usage.
If you want to optimize this particular case just drop down to raw SQL and return JSON from directly your db and stream it back using chunked transfer encoding. Your server's memory usage will only be the size of the buffer used to do the streaming.

Comment: Usually when you have to do joins in EF it's a mistake because your model should represent the relation as a property on the domain model. You should give us what type of a query you are trying to do and how the entire data model looks like. My guess is the query will look like `from product in products from price in product.Prices from customerType in price.CustomerTypePrice where customerType.Type =="TypeOne" select new {product.Name, customer.Price};"` something like that but I am not sure with out more info.

Comment: @FilipCordas In addition my product_price model contains the following properties:
Id
UnitPrice
Product Products (Foreign Key)
CustomerType (Foreign Key)
The CustomerType model contains the following properties:
Id
TypeCategory
Product_Price Product_Prices (Foreign key)

Comment: @GabrielDwight sorry for no response didn't see the response. From what I can see my query should work then with some modifications. But your original query doesn't make sense because you are pulling all products from the db.

Comment: @FilipCordas thanks for your reply. I made some modifications with your query sample and it really helped in fixing the issue of pulling the data that I need with the select statement.